# jQuery trigger h1 color change using CSS and Maximage slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to change the color of a h1 tag depending on the current active slide.

Basically, as the slide changes, so does the h1's color through the use of a `data-main-color` attribute.

I'm using the [Maximage](http://blog.aaronvanderzwan.com/2012/07/maximage-2-0/) slider.

I understand that I've made no attempt to trigger the change on an event, this is where my knowledge has hit a wall... so any help would be great.

**My code**

HTML:

```
        <div id="maximage">
            <div>
                <img src="images/homepage_1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="in-slide-content" data-main-color="#000"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/homepage_2.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="in-slide-content" data-main-color="#FFF"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/homepage_3.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="in-slide-content" data-main-color="#000"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/homepage_4.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="in-slide-content" data-main-color="#FFF"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/homepage_4.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="in-slide-content" data-main-color="#000"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Once Maximage has done its thing:

```
<div id="maximage" class="mc-cycle">

    <div class="mc-image" style="background-image: url(http://box.dev/box-v1.0/images/homepage_1.jpg);">
        <div class="in-slide-content" data-main-color="#000"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mc-image" style="background-image: url(http://box.dev/box-v1.0/images/homepage_2.jpg);">
        <div class="in-slide-content" data-main-color="#FFF"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mc-image" style="background-image: url(http://box.dev/box-v1.0/images/homepage_3.jpg);">
        <div class="in-slide-content" data-main-color="#000"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mc-image" style="background-image: url(http://box.dev/box-v1.0/images/homepage_4.jpg);">
        <div class="in-slide-content" data-main-color="#FFF"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mc-image" style="background-image: url(http://box.dev/box-v1.0/images/homepage_5.jpg);">
        <div class="in-slide-content" data-main-color="#000"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
(function ($) {

    $('#maximage').maximage({
        cycleOptions: {
            pager: '#maximage',
            activePagerClass: 'active',
            fx:'scrollUp',
            easing: 'easeOutSine',
            speed: 1000,
            timeout: 6000,
            prev: '#arrow_left',
            next: '#arrow_right'
        },
        onFirstImageLoaded: function(){
            $('#loader').hide();
            $('#maximage').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });

    $(window).bind("load", function() {

        $(".mc-image").each(function () {

            var mainColor = $(".mc-image.active").find(".in-slide-content").data("main-color");

            $(".page-title > h1").css({
                color: mainColor
            });

        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: avoid using `.bind()` as its been deprecated, use `.on` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Thanku for your code my text get change by doing this..
```

first find currentimage using current object and use that object nd apply your function

```
$(function() {




            $('#maximage').maximage({

                cycleOptions: {

                    fx: 'fade',
                    speed: 6000, // Has to match the speed for CSS transitions in jQuery.maximage.css (lines 30 - 33)
                    timeout: 5000,
                    prev: '#arrow_left',
                    next: '#arrow_right',
                    pause: 0,
                    before: function(last, current) {

                        var myfont = $(current).find(".in-slide-content").data("main-color");
                        $("#about").css({
                        "color":myfont

                    });

                    $("#about>h1").css({
                        "color": myfont

                    });

                        if (!$.browser.msie) {
                            // Start HTML5 video when you arrive
                            if ($(current).find('video').length > 0) $(current).find('video')[0].play();
                        }
                    },
                    after: function(last, current) {

                        if (!$.browser.msie) {
                            // Pauses HTML5 video when you leave it
                            if ($(last).find('video').length > 0) $(last).find('video')[0].pause();
                        }
                    }
                },
                onFirstImageLoaded: function() {
                    jQuery('#cycle-loader').hide();
                    jQuery('#maximage').fadeIn('fast');
                }
            });

            // Helper function to Fill and Center the HTML5 Video
            jQuery('video,object').maximage('maxcover');

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
 (function ($) {

        $('#maximage').maximage({
            cycleOptions: {
                pager: '#maximage',
                activePagerClass: 'active',
                fx:'scrollUp',
                easing: 'easeOutSine',
                speed: 1000,
                timeout: 6000,
                prev: '#arrow_left',
                next: '#arrow_right',
                after: onAfter
            },
            onFirstImageLoaded: function(){
                $('#loader').hide();
                $('#maximage').fadeIn('fast');
            }
        });

        function onAfter() { 
            var mainColor = $(".mc-image.active").find(".in-slide-content").data("main-color");

            $(".page-title > h1").css({
                color: mainColor
            });
        }

    }(jQuery));
```